# Adding Microsoft.Identity.Web to .Net 6 Blazor Webassembly (standalone) app cause an error

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, microsoft-identity-web

I try to add the package Microsoft.Identity.Web to a Blazor Webassembly (standalone) application in .NET 6 and I am getting the error:

"There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier browser-wasm"

I reviewed the Microsoft documentation and I did not find anything related to this package and .NET 6.

Is this package not compatible with this type of project in .NET 6 version?

[Package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFEC6.jpg)

Thanks!!!

Comment: This error happened because this package using netStandard.
Try to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity instead

Comment: For blazor-wasm you should use [Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0)